# Accessing data in filtered array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, uisearchbar

I am implementing UISearchBar and I using filtered array where will be collected matching results. My problem is in TableView I do not know what is the proper way accessing items in "menuItemsFiltered" array. My goal is when searching for a title to display correct Image that assigned to that title. Please help!

```
//Declaring dict arrays:

    var menuItems = [["Name" : "20/20 Cafe", "Image": "20_20Cafe.jpg"],
                        ["Name": "Au Bon Pain", "Image": "AuBonPain.jpg"]]

    var menuItemsFiltered = [(Name:String, Image:UIImage)]()
```

Here is my TableView

```
//Display info in our Residential cells
internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RetailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResidentialTableViewCell

    let entry = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    let anotherEntry = menuItemsFiltered[indexPath.row]


            if self.resultSearch.active
            { //Error in this block
                cell.RetailLabel.text = menuItemsFiltered[indexPath.row]
                //cell.RetailImage.image = anotherEntry
            }
            else
            { //All good here
                cell.RetailImage.image = UIImage(named: entry["Image"]!)
                cell.RetailLabel.text = entry["Name"]!
            }
```

UPDATE: Changed from a dictionary to an array of Tuples:

```
var menuItems = [(name : "20/20 Cafe", image: "20_20Cafe.jpg"),
                    (name: "Au Bon Pain", image: "AuBonPain.jpg")]

var menuItemsFiltered: [(name: String, image: String)] = []
```

In my table view if / else statements

```
if self.resultSearch.active
                {
                    cell.RetailLabel.text = menuItemsFiltered[indexPath.row].name
                    cell.RetailImage.image = UIImage(named: menuItemsFiltered[indexPath.row].image)
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.RetailImage.image = UIImage(named: menuItems[indexPath.row].image)
                    cell.RetailLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row].name
                }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you setting the count correctly in the `numberOfRowsInSection` function?

Comment: Before I was getting an error about improper use of SubScript